# Get custom sort in JTable java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, comparator, tablerowsorter

Hi I want to sort the table data in ascending order and data format is in alphanumeric. I tried using comparator.

below code is to search from Textbox, the problem is while searching the data its not displaying in ascending order.

```
final TableRowSorter<TableModel> tableRowSorter = new TableRowSorter<>(testCasesTable.getModel());
            testCasesTable.setRowSorter(tableRowSorter);

            search.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

                @Override
                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    String text = search.getText();

                    if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
                        tableRowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
                    } else {
                        tableRowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    String text = search.getText();

                    if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
                        tableRowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
                    } else {
                        tableRowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
                }

            });
```

The data passing is through HashMap
Below is the code:

```
HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<String,String>();
        for (int x = 200; x >= 0; x--) {
            data.put("column1 " + (x + 1), "column2 " + (x + 1) );
        }
```

Can anyone provide some example for custom sorting. Thanks.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).  But.. *"Can anyone provide some example for custom sorting"*  ..please don't **ask** for code.  For that, you need a help-desk or tutor.  This is a Q&A site.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - the issue is my code is not working as expected.

Comment: *"..the issue is my code is not working as expected."*  ..try telling me something I **don't** know.  ;)  I don't even understand why you mentioned that.  Where is that MCVE?

Comment: @manish - if you can make your example complete and working, you are helping others to help you. You can explain where your code is not working yet, but providing more of your code saves us from having to add code to enable the program to run.

Comment: @manish - where are `testCasesTable` and `search` coming from, and where is the `data` map used?